# Converting C# object[,] 2D Array to C++ std 2D Array

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling

What would be the best approach to convert a C# 2D object array into C++ std 2D object array.

For example, I have this C# 2d object array:

```
var data = new object[1, 5]; 
data[0, 0] = "1"; 
data[0, 1] = 1.1; 
data[0, 2] = DateTime.Now; 
data[0, 3] = true; 
data[0, 4] = null;
```

How the process of marshaling will look like? - if possible

Are there any good resources which you can recommend related to C# -> C++ marshaling?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The marshalling would look like

1. Make a 2D object array in C++
2. Loop through all indices in the C# array and marshal each object to C++ in its own way
3. Profit

Native code is tricky. You need to know exactly how everything is supposed to be marshalled. And C# doesn't really even attempt at interop with C++ - it's designed for interop with COM, .NET and C-like libraries. It's *kind of* possible, but you really don't want to interop with C++ directly from C#.

If you want interop from .NET to C++, your best bet is C++/CLI - this allows you to combine both native C++ and managed C++ in a single managed assembly. It's still going to be a lot of work, though. Unless you're very experienced in native C++, you'll need to be very careful, since tiny mistakes can propagate easily and break your application in unexpected ways that end up being very hard to debug.

Comment: Hi @luaan thanks for the response. 
Conversion from C# -> C++/CLI is done automatically but to cli:array.
What I am trying to achieve is basically to write a simple wrapper around a big file CSV parser that I've written in C# which is used in MatLab.

To avoid painfully slow conversion from .NET CLI to MatLab cells I want to try to write a wrapper in native c++ and to see if c++ will be interoperable with MatLab IDX(to avoid the cell conversion in MatLab). :)

Comment: @MarjanNikolovski I'm not saying it's automatical - you still need to convert every single object manually. It's just that it's *possible* in C++, because C++ can deal with C++ objects, unlike C#. If you don't need C++ objects, you can use C# - but that doesn't seem to be the case, as per your description.